# Robotic tool changer functionality

Tags: electrical, robotics, mechanical-assembly, industry

Have you any idea how is a changeable end-of-arm tool powered when is interfaced with an ATI tool changer or something similar ? My first thought is that on both sides of parts is a F/M connectors that are precisely fitted.And if that's so, in terms of safety its allowed ?

Comment: Have we any ideas? No, we have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Ok.This is a mechanism that allow a robot to change tools: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDP-oofDn4w&t=114s .And in this video a deburring tool is used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfpin7OCiXg&t=35s .My question is how that electric motor used in deburring  is powered ?